# Where I can find a list of logic gates with non-inverted output?

Tags: logic-gates

I'm doing my homework, where I need to build a pulse duration counter device. I've done it, but now I understand, that every time I build parts of the device, I have to specify the chip, that contains logic elements I used.

I choose a TTL logic, start searching and notice that all elements have inverted output, like AND-NOT. I just can't find chips with elements with non-inverted output, like just AND or OR. Where I can find it?

P.S. it would be excellent, if you provide USSR chips, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, no, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia's [list of 7400-series ICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits) is probably what you're looking for.

Also, note that digital design usually works the other way around: You define the logic you want in some kind of notation (Karnaugh maps, state diagrams, Verilog/VHDL…), and then specify the logic gates you have, and then you (or some software) breaks down the logic you want into the elements you have.

For example, most logic is actually made or NOR and/or NAND gates, not from positive logic.

Comment: Yes, NAND/NOR are the most popular because they are "universal" gates. You can make any other gate using NAND or NOR gates. These are also the easiest gates to manufacture!